# How to change totals of Magento 2 cart

Tags: magento2, php, quote

```
 $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($quote_id);
 $quote->setSubtotalWithDiscount(number_format((float)0, 4, '.', ''));
 $quote->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(number_format((float)0, 4, '.', ''));
 $quote->setGrandTotal(number_format((float)0, 4, '.', ''));
 $quote->setBaseGrandTotal(number_format((float)0, 4, '.', ''));
 if($quote->save())
 {
     echo 'Done';
 }

    It echos data but data is not inserting....
```

Comment: if you print $quote->getData() before save, do you see correct values?

Comment: yes i see updated values after printing and then when i fetch data again it showed the old one

Comment: try with `setData(attribute_name,value)`

Comment: not working i just want to change my totals on some functionality how can i ?

Comment: It's impossible, reinstall last m2 version 2.2.5